# Find records that exists in one table but not another based on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have two tables, billing and weekly.
I need to find values that are in the billing table but not in the weekly table, but I need to base it off of more than one column.
I have a query that works for just one column:

```
SELECT * from billing
outer apply
(select * from weekly where billing.[email]= weekly.[email])a
where a.[email] is null
```

Sometimes in my data the email can change.
So I need to add something if the email doesn't match, check first and last name but do not know how to do this.

Comment: Does Weekly have a foreign key to billing in it?

Comment: I need to make sure either [first name] and [last name] match OR email match.

Comment: Looks like @Mureinik posted the exact answer that I wanted to post. But I am going to post it as an answer anyway since I had it typed up.

Comment: ok so now the query is catching all those, but its missing some i know are not there. So in the table, the data could have same 'first name' 'last name' and 'email' but a sperate colum named 'lender' some of the data goes to 3-4 lenders. So they are not showing up with this query because first name, last name, and email show up with a different lender.

Comment: I added another check in the query, let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `exists` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   billing
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
       (SELECT * 
        FROM   weekly 
        WHERE  billing.[email] = weekly.[email] OR
               (billing.[firstName] = weekly.[firstName] AND
                billing.[lastName] = weekly.[lastName]
               )
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` operator to exclude any records that match in weekly based on email OR first and last name.

```
SELECT bl.*
        FROM billing bl
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM weekly wk
                WHERE (bl.[email] = wk.[email]
                    OR (
                        bl.firstName = wk.firstName
                        AND bl.lastName = wk.lastName))
                    AND bl.lenderName <> wk.lenderName --added this check
                )
```